# Working with let's encrypt ssl certificate and OVH VPS

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, lets-encrypt, ovh

I'm trying to set up https connection in one of my API.
I normally make requests to my API through this address: http://vps234602.ovh.net:8090

I'd like to be able to make https requests.

I tried to make a redirection in OVH panel, from api.uphair.fr to http://vps234602.ovh.net:8090.
Then I used the [zerossl certificate wizard](https://zerossl.com/free-ssl/#crt) to build the certificate.

In the "domains" field, I typed

> www.api.uphair.fr api.uphair.fr

Then I builded the certificate and the DNS verification went well (I was able to add new TXT entries in my DNS zone according to what zerossl was asking).

Then I followed the steps to add this certificate in IIS for my API.
When I'm trying to connect to https://api.uphair.fr the redirection is good but I got the error:

> :ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

I did this for another site in IIS, https://partenaires.uphair.fr and it works well.

Does Anybody know what I'm missing here ? Do I just have to wait for the DNS propagation ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Okay my bad ! ^^